# Regarding Netherlands Schengen visa rejection

Tags: schengen-visas, netherlands, visa-rejections

Recent I applied for Netherlands Schengen visa from India to attend  conference at Rotterdam. Unfortunately my visa 
got rejected even though my documents are fine. I don't have time for appeal process  for reconsidering my application form, since conference dead line is approaching( SEP 20th). Defenetely I should go for reapplying again.

Based on this I have following queries.

1. After rejection, Is there any threshold time such that one can only reapply after that?
2. In Schengen application form there is one question related to fingerprints ( fingerprints collected any time for Schengen visa) do I need to mention yes or no ? since my visa got rejected, i have doubt that what I have to mention when iam reapplying again ?
3. In the cover letter should I need to mention  about my first application rejection or without that normally i need to write ?

Comment: What was the reason given for the refusal? Although there is no threshold time to wait before you may re-apply, there is no point in doing so unless you can address the reason.

Comment: Adding a scan of the refusal letter (with identifying information blacked out) to your Question would help. Use the "edit" button, and attach the image.

Comment: @David Schengen visa refusals are standard forms with a specific set of reasons which can be ticked. It's only necessary to know which boxes are ticked.

Comment: If they have collected your fingerprints, you should mention that. It means your fingerprints are in the Schengen database. If you say there are no fingerprints, there are two problems. You must come to the embassy/consulate for fingerprinting again, when those travel expenses are unnecessary. And if you do give the fingerprints, there will be a database match and it will look like fraud.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.